# IOS developer certificate expires daily

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, provisioning-profile

I have apple account and I am using five mac machine to develop applications. Below Steps are what I am doing

1. I will create CSR from one mac
2. I will create Developer certificate using that CSR
3. I will export the .p12 file from keychain
4. I will install that .p12 file in my other mac machines. So
   that I can use this iOS develoepr certificate on these mac machine
   also.
5. I will create the provisioning profile using that iOS developer certificate.
6. I will run my application into real devices using this provisioning profile.

It works perfectly.

My problem is , It works only for one day , next day it says ,

```
8730250CCE9442D5271EECCC0022CB008ABCBECE: no identity found
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Then I have to revoke my iOS developer certificate , I have to do the same above steps again.

I want to know why I have to do this daily. Is there any solution to solve this ?

Comment: We are also doing the same steps you have mentioned but we are not facing any problems. Please check which Xcode you are using Xcode 7 or Xcode 8. In Xcode it will automatically create the profile. It may also cause the problem.

Comment: xcode shows alert "Fix Issue" , Its not working even after click fix issue button. we are using xcode 7.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely one of your developers is clicking the "Fix Issue" button in Xcode.  That will invalidate the cert that you are creating on the developer portal.  So your certs aren't expiring, someone is revoking them by clicking that "Fix Issue" button.

If you are sharing the private key used for creating the cert, then having each Mac download the cert and provisioning profile from the Apple dev site, you should not get code signing errors in Xcode.  If you are (and are seeing the "Fix Issue" button), you've done something else wrong.

Also, is there a reason you are not using Xcode 8?  Starting with Xcode 8, one developer account can have multiple certificates, which means each Mac can have it's own key / cert for signing.  This means generating a cert / profile on one Mac shouldn't invalidate the cert for the other Macs.

The biggest lesson is that you should never use the "Fix Issue" button if you have one apple developer account and are using it on multiple Macs.  It will inevitably cause more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 0):

If the certificate is expired, you can not revoke it. You need to re-create it through the developer program portal.

Once you have your new certificate available, I am not sure if you need to create again the provisioning profiles associated to your previous certificate. I guess you must probably do this (unless the provisioning profiles just use the certificate subject and not the valid from/ to fieds).

if above is not worked, Please follow this link.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html